# Track User Activity on Remote Site

Tags: usability-testing

I'm working on a **usability testing service** and trying to figure out how to track user activity (e.g. url, clicks etc.) on a page of another domain (*without modifying the page via JS or similar*).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd have to modify the page in some way through the browser to do most of the stuff you need. Perhaps a Firefox extension, or hooking up events (if they are available) on WebKit/Gecko controls.

Or, you *might* be able to hack something together with an `<iframe>` and some JavaScript monitoring for clicks. I'm not sure how you could pass the clicks on to the iframe, though.

But other than that, I don't think it's possible - and probably for good reason! It'd be quite a big security hole.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to "see" through an iframe that is pointing to another domain, so a Firefox extension is about the extent of your options I would say.

Comment: Thanks for the input!
I think AIR has some browser-like capabilities - maybe I could use this (although I would have preferred to no install anything). I also thought about using a proxy between user and website which does the according modifications (possible? makes sense?)

Comment: A proxy might work, but you'd be limited to the amount of data you could record with *just* the proxy. I think some client-side tool is n eccessary. I'm not sure about AIR.